# How do I install a newer version of R on 9.10?

Tags: 9.10, r

I am trying to install R on my ubuntu 9.10 machine but when I use the repository I tend to get the R version 2.8 which is quite old. Is  there a way to install R latest version on my machine. Ubuntu Upgrade are not possible now. Or is it possible  to use packages from the Lucid Lynx packages for my installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you installing R in Ubuntu 9.04 or 9.10? Title says 9.04 while the message says 9.10
Anyway, both are not supported anymore (please see this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), so you should upgrade to a more recent release to have a newer R and you could also follow these instructions: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/